# hex colors change depending of a select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, colors, hex

I'm creating an background color editor in my web site. Basically I would do match certain colors depending on the color chosen by the user it-self.
For example, based on the color added... i would get two type of colors (**lighter** and **darker**).

So, with this hex `#a5cedb` the lighter color matching is this `#f6fafb`, while darker is this `#739099`.

Now, is there a script that finds the exact color match based on this example? 
Following this principle, I should be able to find `#fafcf6`(lighter) and `#919a72`(darker) by inserting this hex `#d0dca4`

I'm asking too much or is there already something that does this?

(...sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You need to convert the hex value to RGB values, then decrease/increase each RGB value, and convert back to hex. [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [`Number.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) functions will help you to convert bases.

Comment: http://goo.gl/t1RYwk solved with this way

Answer (score 1):

You can use thee following function to convert the hex to integer:

```
function hex2int(h) { 
       return parseInt(h, 16);
 }

alert(hex2int('dd66ab'))
```

than you can compare:

```
if(hex2int('dd66ab')>hex2int('fafcf6')){
       //do somethig
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at these plugins for found your solution:

http://davidwalsh.name/color-palette-generator-jquery

http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/

http://enideo.com/code/jquery-colors-plugin/

please explain more !

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48746447/color.jpg this is the photoshop way to get my ideas... now is it possible with something plugin or script ? if it is possible ! :D

Comment: @MarioRossi Looks like your example just changes the alpha value in `rgba(R, G, B, alpha)`.